# SVG logo is not filled

Tags: svg, css-animations, keyframe, svg-animate

[image]I have logo of client in SVG, i created a "draw" animation but there is a space between lines (as you can see on the image)

When i use "fill: white;" on the "path" element, the fill is there instantly so the "draw" animation is almost invisible. I also tried to create a new @Keyframe to that but the fill instantly appears after the animation and also in a couple of seconds instantly disappears.. when i set the "stroke-width" to for example 7px, its filled but now its too wide.. The code:

```
<div class="box">
  <svg class="svg-logo" width="740" height="454" viewbox="0 0 740 454">
   <path class="outline" d="*SVG PATH*" stroke: "white" stroke-opacity:".5" stroke-minerlimit="10">
   <path class="outline" d="*SVG PATH*" stroke: "white" stroke-opacity:".5" stroke-minerlimit="10">

   <path class="circle" d="*SVG PATH*" stroke: "white" stroke-minerlimit="10">
   <path class="circle" d="*SVG PATH*" stroke: "white" stroke-minerlimit="10">
  </svg>
 </div>
```

```
.svg-logo {
    max-width:700px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    stroke-dasharray: 10000;
    animation: 15s write;
}
@keyframes write {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 10000; 
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: See [my tutorial](https://browser-unplugged.net/blog/calligraphy.en.html) how to solve this.

Comment: Did not helped me at all :/ it is still too wide with it

Comment: Did you understand that you do not have to _stroke_ the logo shape but to _fill_ it? Only then, draw a line over the filled shape, give it a stroke so it covers the shape, then use that as a mask and animate that second line.